# "False reasoning" psychiatric term

Tags: terminology, psychology

I am looking for a one word English equivalent for "false reasoning" of schizophrenia patients. There are two type of this - one is non pathological when low-educated people explain some phenomenon on a base of their own limited knowledge. The second type, is pathological - when people explain phenomenon as a consequence of a disease.

Thanks.

Comment: It sounds to me as though the first type of faulty reasoning you refer to falls into the general category of [cognitive bias](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cognitive_bias).

Comment: There are much more than just two types of false reasoning, and even the two types you mention can both be divided into many different types. What exactly is it you're looking for here?

Answer (score 1):

Could *[fallacy](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/fallacy)* be the word you are looking for?

> an incorrect or misleading notion or opinion based on inaccurate facts or invalid reasoning
> 2. unsound or invalid reasoning
> 3. the tendency to mislead
> 4. (Logic) logic an error in reasoning that renders an argument logically invalid
> [C15: from Latin fallācia, from fallax deceitful, from fallere to deceive].

*NOTE*: having had another look at your question and having thought this through a bit, I'd say [*delusion*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/delusion*) is a better option as it applies to both states described (source: Merriam-Webster Online Dictionary):

> a. a belief that is not true, a false idea
>
> b. a false idea or belief caused by mental illness.

Answer (score 0):

I think [delirium](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Delirium) can  be used to refer to   what you are describing:

> - A temporary state of mental confusion and fluctuating consciousness resulting from high fever, intoxication, shock, or other causes. It is characterized by anxiety, disorientation, hallucinations, delusions, and incoherent speech.

Source: The American Heritage® Dictionary of the English Language.

[Intrusive thoughts](https://www.panicaway.com/word/articles/intrusive-thoughts) is another expression related to what you are asking. Intrusive thoughts may lead to delirium:

> - An intrusive thought is a thought or image that pops into mind on a frequent, uncontrolled basis causing us distress, frustration, or upset. The intrusive thought could be anything that disturbs you, such as losing control, making a mistake, health worry, or unsettling thoughts about others. It is as if the more you try to block the thought or image out the more it comes back to hang you.

Source:http://www.spectrumhealth.ie/managing-intrusive-thoughts/

Comment: I mean the normal consciousness state, while delirium is absolutely pathologic condition. I mean "false reasoning" alone as a permanent condition which is part of a norma (religions etc), and pathologic reasoning which is part of psychiatric disease, but without consciousness changes.

Comment: I see, but in your question you appear to ask for a term referring to a pathology. I suggest you rephrase you question.